# jquery animate help

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ok, so i am trying to replicate this animation at the top of this website: 
http://www.infinvision.com/insights-and-musings.html

I have the animation working, the container div animates to the top of the screen correctly. however, on my version the content within the div just stays there, while the enclosing div closes around it. In the website I am copying the content seems to move up with the closing div. I have tried to set the div position value to absolute and try to animate the top property to zero, however this doesn't work. Any suggestions?????

thanks,
daniel.

EDIT: HTML Code i am using:

```
<div id="toplogin">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="toploginWrap">
    <div id="topLwrap"> MORE STUFF HERE  </div>
    <div id="topRwrap">
      <h3><span>LOGIN</span>
      </h3>
      <form id="topLoginFm" action="" method="POST">
         MORE STUFF HERE 
      </form>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT code i am using:

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('#loginButton').click(function() {
    $('#toplogin' ).animate({
        padding: 0,
        margin:0,
        height: 'toggle'

  }, 1000, function() {

    });

});
};



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the content moving up with the closing div, see http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/CPHxq/2/.

Making the div position fixed keeps it in place as the content moves up.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this http://jsfiddle.net/79qvv/1/

The only change I did is that am not using window.OnLoad ... Instead I am binding the click handler once the dom is ready. You would normally do it as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //your custom code here ...
});
</script>
```

The rest of the code in the fiddle is exactly what you posted ... Hope this helped ...